# i have just begun to use android studio and i cant seem to get my gradle to sync with my application. here is what it shows :

Tags: android-studio

7:46:20 PM Gradle sync started

7:46:35 PM Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
           This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
           For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
           Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
           Please read the following process output to find out more:
           -----------------------
           Error occurred during initialization of VM
           Could not reserve enough space for object heap
           Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
           Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

the jvm version is 1.7.0_79

and the studio version is 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

There's no space available in RAM. To fix go to /android-studio-dir/bin and edit studio.vmoptions and studio64.vmoptions to increment the -Xmx and to reserve more memory to Java. Note that the number of processes active may influence on that.

Comment: @Nandish19 Note that Java 8 is required unless you are in a Mac environment (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Probably, the /tmp location is full..

Found this somewhere..
Use df command

```
df
```

You should see an output with a line like this:

```
tmpfs 102400 102312 88 100% /tmp
```

So to change the size of the tmp file:

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=2G /tmp
```

Done! Now, It should work..